# can I install the developer edition of power BI Report server in the organization I work for and create a portal in the local environment?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I want to configure Power BI Report Server and install the **Developer** edition. Am I able to create a Power BI portal without any limitations? Or this edition does not let us run portals in the local environment!!
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

The developer and evaluation editions can be installed, there are no restrictions on the features or product limitations.

The limitation is on the use of the PBI Report Server. If you use it to deliver reports or data to end users that is based on a production/live system you will break the terms of the license.

If you develop reports based on a development data source, then that is fine. You can then push those reports up to a production/live PBI Report server if that ones meets the production environment licensing.